# how to support the screen readers to know the focused value in div and td element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, accessibility, screen-readers

`enter code here`replication procedure:`enter code here`

[JQuery DatePicker sample link](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

1. Open the attached link.
2. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> key outside the datePicker control
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> the focusing Date will change.
4. I need to say currently the users focusing date is what?

Can you help me, how to give the support for users focused date into the screen readers. i have tried the `aria-label` and `aria-selected` attributes but not works correctly.

Like this I have colorPicker palate support sample in that sample I have the value for `div` element I have the same attribute (`aria-label` and `aria-selected`) in here also, but not works.

Can you please suggest me if there is an another way is present or my mistake in this.

```css
table,td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
table,td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Add a border to a table:</h2>
<div>July</div>
<table cellspacing="2" role="grid" aria-activedescendant="cb854b9f-8f91-42d7-a55f-6ca1c5c39310_cell_selected">
<thead>
<tr  role="row">
<th scope="col" abbr="Sunday" date="Sunday" title="Sunday" >Su</th>
<th scope="col" abbr="Monday" date="Monday" title="Monday" >Mo</th>
<th scope="col" abbr="Tuesday" date="Tuesday" title="Tuesday" >Tu</th>
<th scope="col" abbr="Wednesday" date="Wednesday" title="Wednesday" >We</th>
<th scope="col" abbr="Thursday" date="Thursday" title="Thursday" >Th</th>
<th scope="col" abbr="Friday" date="Friday" title="Friday" >Fr</th>
<th scope="col" abbr="Saturday" date="Saturday" title="Saturday" >Sa</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody ><tr role="row">
<td date="Sun Jun 25 2017" title="Sun Jun 25 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell"  style="visibility: visible;">25</td>
<td date="Mon Jun 26 2017" title="Mon Jun 26 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell"  style="visibility: visible;">26</td>
<td date="Tue Jun 27 2017" title="Tue Jun 27 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell" style="visibility: visible;">27</td>
<td date="Wed Jun 28 2017" title="Wed Jun 28 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell" style="visibility: visible;">28</td>
<td date="Thu Jun 29 2017" title="Thu Jun 29 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell" style="visibility: visible;">29</td>
<td date="Fri Jun 30 2017" title="Fri Jun 30 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell" style="visibility: visible;">30</td>
<td date="Sat Jul 01 2017" title="Sat Jul 01 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell" >1</td></tr>

<tr role="row">
<td date="Sun Jul 02 2017" title="Sun Jul 02 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell" >2</td>
<td date="Mon Jul 03 2017" title="Mon Jul 03 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell" >3</td>
<td date="Tue Jul 04 2017" title="Tue Jul 04 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell" >4</td>
<td date="Wed Jul 05 2017" title="Wed Jul 05 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">5</td>
<td date="Thu Jul 06 2017" title="Thu Jul 06 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">6</td>
<td date="Fri Jul 07 2017" title="Fri Jul 07 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">7</td>
<td date="Sat Jul 08 2017" title="Sat Jul 08 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell" >8</td></tr>

<tr role="row"><td date="Sun Jul 09 2017" title="Sun Jul 09 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell" >9</td>
<td date="Mon Jul 10 2017" title="Mon Jul 10 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">10</td>
<td date="Tue Jul 11 2017" title="Tue Jul 11 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">11</td>
<td date="Wed Jul 12 2017" title="Wed Jul 12 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">12</td>
<td date="Thu Jul 13 2017" title="Thu Jul 13 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">13</td>
<td date="Fri Jul 14 2017" title="Fri Jul 14 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">14</td>
<td date="Sat Jul 15 2017" title="Sat Jul 15 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell" >15</td></tr>

<tr role="row">
<td date="Sun Jul 16 2017" title="Sun Jul 16 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell" >16</td>
<td date="Mon Jul 17 2017" title="Mon Jul 17 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">17</td>
<td date="Tue Jul 18 2017" title="Tue Jul 18 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell" >18</td>
<td date="Wed Jul 19 2017" title="Wed Jul 19 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">19</td>
<td date="Thu Jul 20 2017" title="Thu Jul 20 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">20</td>
<td date="Fri Jul 21 2017" title="Fri Jul 21 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">21</td>
<td date="Sat Jul 22 2017" title="Sat Jul 22 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell" >22</td></tr><tr role="row">
<td date="Sun Jul 23 2017" title="Sun Jul 23 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell" >23</td>
<td date="Mon Jul 24 2017" title="Mon Jul 24 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">24</td>
<td date="Tue Jul 25 2017" title="Tue Jul 25 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">25</td>
<td date="Wed Jul 26 2017" title="Wed Jul 26 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">26</td>
<td date="Thu Jul 27 2017" title="Thu Jul 27 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">27</td>
<td date="Fri Jul 28 2017" title="Fri Jul 28 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">28</td>
<td date="Sat Jul 29 2017" title="Sat Jul 29 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell" >29</td></tr><tr role="row">
<td date="Sun Jul 30 2017" title="Sun Jul 30 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell" >30</td>
<td date="Mon Jul 31 2017" title="Mon Jul 31 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">31</td>
<td date="Tue Aug 01 2017" title="Tue Aug 01 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell"  style="visibility: visible;">1</td>
<td date="Wed Aug 02 2017" title="Wed Aug 02 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell"  style="visibility: visible;">2</td>
<td date="Thu Aug 03 2017" title="Thu Aug 03 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell"  style="visibility: visible;">3</td>
<td date="Fri Aug 04 2017" title="Fri Aug 04 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell"  style="visibility: visible;">4</td>
<td date="Sat Aug 05 2017" title="Sat Aug 05 2017" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell"  style="visibility: visible;">5</td></tr></tbody></table>

</body>
</html>
```

like this and i have attached my output on the image there while navigate the dates through the keyBoard using right/left/up/down arrow keys i have include the  "aria-label, data-value, id" attributes like aria-lable="focusing date is : 12/7/2017" data-value:"12/7/2017" id="cb854b9f-8f91-42d7-a55f-6ca1c5c39310_cell_selected"(same as tables aria-activedescendant attribute value)

but not work. the expecting result is when focus the date "13/7/2017" the screen reader should be says my aria-lable value with column no.

Comment: Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve What code have you tried? Please understand that we cannot help improve your code if you have not shared it with us. Also members will not write code for you.

Comment: Hi @Twisty , i have attach my code block here.could you please right me to my expecting output.